# Add custom claims to Azure Active Directory token calling APIs

Tags: azure-active-directory

I want to rely on Azure Active Directory to protect apps and APIs. The end users are the employees of the company (they are in the AD). We have a very specific configuration for security that implies to get information outside Active Directory and to add them as claims in the token.

So my question is the following:

Is there a way in Azure Active Directory to add custom claims by calling rest APIs?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims
I know that I can do that in Azure B2C with custom policies.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile

Or could I use Azure B2C for that with a custom policy even if the end users are our employees ?  :
Step 1: rely on Azure AD as an OIDC provider
Step 2: call rest API
Step 3: forge and return the token

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add custom claims to access token using claims mapping policy.

Expose an API on the application

Call the API to pass the claims in the access token

Reference Links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#configuring-optional-claims
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens